# Azure B2C Blade in Azure Portal Missing

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

The questions root cause was a transient narrow Azure B2C portal run time detail that was specific to some Edge browsers on my network - about 1 in 5. Edge always worked In Private Mode and Chrome always worked.  **This question and its premise is now moot. - will probably delete this question if I can**.

The following Screen is not reachable in Azure Portal Right now across many subscriptions and tenants.  It is like “Azure AD B2C” is missing as a resource type within the Azure portal. (2018-June-16)

**Workaround Found – Use Chrome – This is an Edge Browser Specific Problem**  *(In Private also seems to fix it)*

[image: Azure AD B2C Settings on Azure Portal]

It is like something changed in the Azure Portal regarding the B2C management Blade.  My B2C tenants are running fine.  Lack of Access to the B2C management Blades in Azure Portal could be a production issue to some people.

I see the same “missing” behavior in 3 of my subscriptions and tenants …. 
The portal dashboard pin now looks like this …

[image: DashboardLinkBad]

I always relied on the dashboard link – **Does anyone know the Deep Link or direct url to this blade?  I could manually make a url for my tenant and try to see if I can get to it directly.**

*(In Progress Followup)*
Ramakrishna got me the top blade link. - Thank You

**Workaround Found – Use Chrome – This is an Edge Browser Specific Problem**
[image: Edge Specific Error]

Comment: Did you try, Navigate to your tenant in Portal -> All Services - > Type B2C and choose -> Azure AD B2C and see whether it is loading or not?

Comment: YES - that worked - FYI the deep link is .. https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_B2CAdmin/TenantManagementMenuBlade/overview    I can not pin it to my dashboard.  Also the "parent billing subscription" lost its link into the B2C tenant across all my subscriptions.  I have to manually switch tenant directories now.

Comment: @SqlSurfer, if you have a repro or trace details, you can help b2c by sending an email to AADB2CPreview@microsoft.com.  Here is the link to service blog published by b2c - 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureadb2c/2018/06/16/azure-ad-b2c-blade-load-errors-impacting-small-set-of-customers-intermittently/

Comment: Chrome Works – Edge Does Not.   Using Chrome I was able to see everything as normal on the B2C blade.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be addressed to the azure-portal support.